# No me funciona el bucle infinito en Python en Raspberry

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi

Llevos un par de semanas intentando hacer funcionar mi código Python en una Raspberry Pi4,
y hay veces en las que el código funciona bien y hay otras en las que no y no sé cual puede ser la causa.
Lo que hace el código es abrir 3 pestañas en google proyectando en cada pestaña la monitorización de cada página web (que previamente inicia sesión en ellas), antes de entrar al bucle hace un <kbd>F11</kbd> para agrandar la pantalla y después entra en el bucle que es donde me viene el problema. Una vez ha aumentado la pantalla se supone que debe entrar en el bucle, pero hay veces en las que lo hace y otras que no. Lo que hace el bucle es pulsar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> para que cambie de pestaña cada 20 segundos y así que se vaya viendo las monitorizaciones, ya que mi intención es hacer un bucle infinito.

En el código también podeis ver que utilizo la librería *Keyboard* para agrandar la página y el *pyautogui* para pasar de pestañas en el bucle, eso es porque me ha funcionado mejor así, porque también han habido veces en las que he puesto el *pyautogui* para poner la pantalla completa y también me ha fallado.

Aquí teneis mi código para que me podais echar una mano y poder ver en qué me he equivocado.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import pynput
import time
import keyboard
import pyautogui

keyboard = Controller()

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")


print("Test case started")  
# Maximize window
driver.maximize_window()


# Navigate to the url  
driver.get("https://region01eu5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/pvmswebsite/assets/build/index.html#/home/kpi")
time.sleep(3)


# Get element
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Type email
username.send_keys('correo.com')

#Get element password
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'value')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Type password
password.send_keys('contraseña')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

time.sleep(4)


# Click on login
Buton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btn_outerverify')
time.sleep(2)

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

Buton.click()

#click second login
Boton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'confirmedLogin')
time.sleep(2)

Boton.click()

time.sleep(4)

driver.get("https://region01eu5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/pvmswebsite/assets/build/index.html#/home/kpi")

time.sleep(15)

driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

# Maximize window
driver.maximize_window()


# Navigate to the url
driver.get('https://www.solarweb.com/PvSystems/Widgets')
time.sleep(4)


# Get element
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Type email
username.send_keys('correo')

#Get element password
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Type password
password.send_keys('contraseña')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

time.sleep(4)

# Click on login
Buton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'submitButton')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

Buton.click()

time.sleep(4)

#Deny cookies
cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonDecline')
cookie.click()
time.sleep(4)

# Maximize window
driver.maximize_window()


time.sleep(15)

# Maximize window
driver.maximize_window()

driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])

# Navigate to the url  
driver.get("https://www.ingeconsunmonitor.com/login")
time.sleep(3)

# Get element
username = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="username")

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Type email
username.send_keys('correo')

#Get element password
password = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="password")

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Type password
password.send_keys('contraseña')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

time.sleep(4)

# Click on login
Buton = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/app-main-login/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/app-login/div/div/form/div[3]/div/button/span")

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

Buton.click()

time.sleep(15)   

#Pantalla completa
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press(Key.f11)
keyboard.release(Key.f11)
time.sleep(1)
# Bucle


while (x):
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'Tab')
    
    time.sleep(20)
    

print('Test case completed')
```

Comment: No necesitas de `keyboard` ni `pyautogui`. Selenium ya puede hacer eso

Comment: Vale y cual sería el comando para poder poner la pantalla completa y el comando para poder ir cambiando de pestaña del  buscador en el bucle ?

Comment: Tienes que crear un objeto `Options` y añadir el argumento `--kiosk`. Para cambiar de tab debes buscar el tab en `driver.window_handles` y usas `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`. Si nada de esto te funciona igual puedes `ActionChains` para emular el presionar las teclas.

Comment: He hecho la prueba y no me a funcionado. Cuando va a hacer el Fullscreen, lo hace y después se quita, y no pasa de pestaña en pestaña.